# How to perform OCR for several contours

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I have a code that identifies contours in a licence plates, however I don't know how to extract the letters using pytesseract for each individual contour. This is the original image:

[image]

This is the code:

```
        import cv2
        import numpy as np
        import pytesseract


        image = cv2.imread('c1.png')
        cv2.waitKey(0)


        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


        edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        blured = cv2.blur(gray, (5,5), 0)    
        img_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blured, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
        rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (30, 10))
        threshed = cv2.morphologyEx(img_thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, rect_kernel)

        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged,
            cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        for contour in contours:
            if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 170:
                [X, Y, W, H] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                cv2.rectangle(image, (X, Y), (X + W, Y + H), (0,0,255), 2)
                
                mask = np.zeros(gray.shape,np.uint8)
                new_image = cv2.drawContours(mask,[contour],0,255,-1,)
                new_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image,mask=mask)
                (x, y) = np.where(mask == 255)
                (topx, topy) = (np.min(x), np.min(y))
                (bottomx, bottomy) = (np.max(x), np.max(y))
                
                Cropped0 = gray[topx:bottomx+2, topy:bottomy+2]


        cv2.imshow('Canny Edges After Contouring', edged)
        cv2.waitKey(0)


        print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours)))
        result_number = pytesseract.image_to_string(new_image, lang='eng')
        print("Detected Number is:",result_number)

        cv2.imshow('Contours', image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.imshow('new_image', Cropped0)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output of the code:

[image]

I tried cropping the image after identifying the contours for the OCR but it only crops number 5 for some reason. Also I would like to ignore the contours containing Arabic letters would it be possible to exclude these two from the recognition process?. Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Finding contours on the edge image is giving you inconsistent contours.

In the following code I have done:

- Otsu threshold on the grayscale image and inverted the result `th`
- Found contours on `th` and cropped them based on area

**Code:**

```
# Function to show image:
def show(img):
    cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

img = cv2.imread('image_path')
img1 = img.copy()
img_g = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

th = cv2.threshold(img_g,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for contour in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 170:
        [X, Y, W, H] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(img1, (X, Y), (X + W, Y + H), (0,0,255), 2)
        Cropped0 = th[Y - 2:Y + H +2, X - 2:X + W + 2]
        show(Cropped0)
```

**Results:**

`th` result:

[image]

`img1` result:

[image]

Some cropped digits:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: OMG this actually worked, thank you so much x. I added these lines of code 'result_number = pytesseract.image_to_string(Cropped0, lang='eng')
        print("Detected Number is:",result_number)' inside the for loop but it is still unable to read the numbers it will run but I don't think with this method is able to identify the numbers and letters

Comment: @YA you can try resizing the cropped images and feed it

Comment: I tried that and I also played with configurations but nothing worked it literally either prints out a random character or nothing at all :(

Comment: @YA how about reducing the thickness of the characters in the cropped images, erosion?

Comment: After some research I realised that finding the coordinates and then grouping them would work. So yah I will try that. Thank you so much for your help it really made me move a step closer to my goal I remember appreciate it.